# How to request a query JSON in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I just want to ask on how to or possible to request a GET in retrofit using the JSON as Query?

for example:

*`https://www.mywebsite.com/api/location?data=["1"]`*
*`https://www.mywebsite.com/api/location?data=["1","2"]`*

So far, this is what I did, and maybe I think this is wrong?

```
@GET("/api/location")
fun getLocationData(@Query("data") data: String) // data value = "["1", "2"]"
```

any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what I have:
In this example, with @Path you can add the variable in the url

```
@GET(Constante.HERO_DETAIL + "/{hero_id}")
Call<DataMaster> getHeroDetail(
        @Path("hero_id") Integer hero_id
);
```

Other example:

```
@GET(Constante.HERO_LIST)
Call<DataMaster> getHeroList(
        @Query("token") String token,
        @Query("gameLevel") String gameLevel,
        @Query("section") String section
);
```

I think you are in a good way.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try below
@GET("/api/location/data={x}")
fun getLocationData(@Query("x") myarrdata: String)